# Keep Cloud Run task running after client close connection

Tags: react-native, express, google-cloud-run

I deployed the following Api on Google Cloud Run

```
const app = express();

app.use(function(req, res, next){
    req.setTimeout(12000000, function(){
        // call back function is called when request timed out.
    });
    next();
});

app.get('/', async(req, res) => {

    const id = req.query.id

    try {
    const doneWithSuccuss = await run(id)

    if(doneWithSuccuss){
     res.send("Succuess " + id);
   }else{
     res.send("Fail " + id);;
   }
 } catch (e){
   res.send("Error " + id);
 }

});
```

The run function take a long time to process, around 10 minutes. Once it's done, a push notification is sent to the client which is a smartphone. This is how I call on function in the client

```
try {
      const response = await fetch(
        `https://someurl.com/?id=${id}`
      );
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
```

If the user keep the application in the foreground, everything is working fine. If the application is sent to the background, the Api is called multiple time and is acting very bizarre. Probably because the Http call is closed by the client.

Is there a way ignore the fact that the Https call is closed by the client on Cloud Run? Or is it possible to directly send a response to the client after receiving the request, and then start the run function? So keep the revision running after responsing to the client. Or do you have any other advise?

Comment: Use always on CPU feature.

Comment: Can you explain?

Comment: Does it enough? https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/serverless/cloud-run-gets-always-on-cpu-allocation